Lenovo thinkpad E14 gen5 amd ryzen 5 is not supporting usb bootable pendrive for ubuntu
I have Lenovo thinkpad E14 gen5 amd ryzen 5 with windows 11 pre installed. I want to install ubuntu on the machine but the bootable usb drive not detected. Also i tried by disabling secure boot and enabling Microsoft 3rd party UEFI CA, but it doesn't work.
Please help !!!

Update your original question with some more information. Saying "it's not detected" and "it does not work" does not explain much. Have you followed the user guide sections about installing an OS? Have you looked at the boot options/priority menu in the BIOS? Does it ever show the USB drive? Have you pressed F12 during boot (on some Lenovo models this goes to a boot menu, although I don't know about your model).

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
